# Getting text of attribute in xml using vtd-xml in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

Given the following xml:

```
<JUT>
    <DDT>
        <SSG q="textGoal">Lorem ipsum...</SSG>
    </DDT>
    ....
    ...
</JUT>
```

I am using vtd-xml with XPath in order to retrieve 'textGoal' as follows:

```
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        vg.setDoc(xmlContent);
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        int node = 0;

        ap.selectXPath("//SSG[1]/@q");
        node = ap.evalXPath();
        if(node != -1) {
            myString = vn.toString(node);
        }
```

This gives myString as 'q' and not 'textGoal'. I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. I know that 'textGoal' is URL-escaped. Does vtd-xml do URL-UNescape or do I have to do this myself?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `vn.getAttributeVal(vn.toString(node))`

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it is

```
vn.toString(node+1)
```

assuming node is not -1. As to the URL escaping, part, you have `toString()`, `toRawString()`, and `toNormalizedString()` to choose from

Comment: But what to do when my path is variable? How should I know if it requests an attribute (call `getAttributeVal(vn.toString(node))` or `toString(node+1)`) or not (call `toString(node)`)?

Comment: What do you mean by variable path?

Comment: The user can put in the XPath `/foo/bar/text()`, `/foo/bar/@attr` or `/foo[@attr='baz']/bar/text()` - I don't know. How do I know which of the vtd-xml methods to use? Or why isn't there an all-in-one method?

Comment: because there are different user requirements... this has to do with the xml spec of the treatment of string.... In general, toString() is the most common

Comment: @Alex did you ever get a generic solution in the case where your xpath is a variable, and you wouldn't know a priori if it's an attribute or not?

Comment: I think that xpath evaluation returning attribute name node index is consistent with thw design goal of vtd-xml. One general solution would be to use autopilot's evalPathToString method which directly gives you attr val string.

Comment: Thanks, evalXPathToString works although it's not perfect. Do you think it's possible to add a .isAttribute method to the Navigator? There is already an .isElement()

Comment: @GeorgeSofianos  --sorry I do not understand... can you provide an example of your suggested isAttribute? I don't know isElement() is there ...

Comment: Actually you are right, it's not actually "there". It's a protected method in VTDNav.java - I think I only used it in my debugger but I remember it returns false for an attribute node - I suppose this can't be used to check if the XPath result is an element or an attribute?